# phing and phpunit + bootstrap

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, testing, phpunit, phing

How to run PHPUnit test suite with bootstrap file with phing?

My app structure:

```
application/
library/
tests/
  application/
  library/
  bootstrap.php
  phpunit.xml
build.xml
```

phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory
              suffix=".php">../library/</directory>
            <directory
              suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory
                  suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

then:

```
cd /path/to/app/tests/
phpunit
#all test passed
```

But how do I run the tests from `/path/to/app/` dir? The problem is, that the `bootstrap.php` depends on relative paths to library and application.

If I run `phpunit --configuration tests/phpunit.xml /tests` I got a bunch of file not found errors.

How do I write `build.xml` file for `phing` to run the tests the same way `phpunit.xml` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Think the best way is to create an small PHP Script to initalize your Unit tests, iam doing the following:

In my phpunit.xml / bootstrap="./initalize.php"

**initalize.php**

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
define('APPLICATION_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/application');

// Include path
set_include_path(
    '.'
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . BASE_PATH . '/library'
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
);

// Define application environment
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');
require_once 'BaseTest.php';
```

**BaseTest.php**

```
abstract class BaseTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

/**
 * Application
 *
 * @var Zend_Application
 */
public $application;

/**
 * SetUp for Unit tests
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setUp()
{
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    $this->application = new Zend_Application(
                    APPLICATION_ENV,
                    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
    );

    $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');

    Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled;

    parent::setUp();
}

/**
 * Bootstrap
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function appBootstrap()
{
    $this->application->bootstrap();
}
}
```

All my Unit tests are extending BaseTest Class, it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. This is more or less my `bootstrap.php`. My problem was I didn't know I can specify the bootstrap param in phing this way: `phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --configuration tests/phpunit.xml`

Answer (score 3):

When you use the PHPUnit tasks in Phing, you can include your bootstrap file like this:

```
<target name="test">
    <phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
        <formatter type="summary" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="tests">
                <include name="**/*Test.php"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </phpunit> 
</target>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use phpunit.xml when calling phpunit this way in phing.